# The theme is not changed correctly in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, themes

[image]

I am using the Dracula theme, but there are parts of the code that do not display correctly as shown in the graphic.

When I start the editor everything loads correctly, but after a few milliseconds it changes and does not respect the theme, is there any configuration that has to be done to make it respect the theme?

Answer (score 0):

Just save all the projects and android studio settings. Then uninstall android studio and reinstall it.

**OR**

Simply restore the setting to default, like so:

Screenshot:
[image]
[image]